# jQueryUI Slider is not scrolling div

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

I am new to jquery, so apologies if this is a lengthy question. The following is what I have come up with for a horizontal slider to scroll a div containing lists of images.
The result is the slider not scrolling the div. Any help would be great.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var slideDrag,
slideWidth = 330,
slideSpeed = 200;
animated = false;

    $(".scroll-slider").slider({
    animate: slideSpeed,
    start: checkType,
    slide: doSlide,
    max: slideWidth 
});


    // Set each slider to a value
    $(".scroll-slider").each(function(index){
        $(this).slider("value", 330 / 5 * index);
    });

    // You can also change a slider at any time like so:
    // $(".scroll-slider:eq(0)").slider("value", value);
    //
    // That would move the first slider to a value, along with its content

    function checkType(e){
        slideDrag = $(e.originalEvent.target).hasClass("ui-slider-handle");
    }

    function doSlide(e, ui){
        var target = $(e.target).prev(".scroll-content"),
        // If sliders were above the content instead of below, we'd use:
        // target = $(e.target).next(".scroll-content")
        maxScroll = target.attr("scrollWidth") - target.width();

        // Need to check type now to prevent the new change handler from firing twice when user clicks on slider,
        // because both 'slide' and 'change' events are fired on a click, but only a 'change' when setting slider
        // value manually via code.
        if (e.type == 'slide'){
            // Was it a click or drag?
            if (slideDrag === true){
                // User dragged slider head, match position
                target.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / slideWidth) });
            }
            else{
                // User clicked on slider itself, animate to position
                target.stop().animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / slideWidth) }, slideSpeed);
            }
            animated = true;
        }
        else{
            if (animated === false){
                target.stop().animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / slideWidth) }, slideSpeed);
            }
            animated = false;
        }
    }

});
</script>

</script>

<style>
    /* Styling the scroll elements */
        .scroll-container{padding-bottom:30px}
        .scroll-content{width:330px;height:110px;overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:10px}

        .scroll-content ul{
            width:880px; 
            height:110px; 
            margin-bottom:5px
        }
        .scroll-content li{
            float:left; 
            }
        .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle{width:16px;height:12px;position:absolute;top:-3px;background:#234786;border:none}
    </style>




  <body>  
   <div id="wrapper">
    <h2>Multiple Slider Control Demo</h2>
    <div id="left">
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <div class="scroll-content">
                <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-slider"></div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the ready to go sample on jQuery UI page? --> http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to work from this demo?

http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/div-slide/

I had the same error, and replaced the version of `jQuery` I was using with the one used in the demo and it worked.